# looking for some network video camera to program against

Tags: .net, video, networking, camera

I am looking for a network camera which I could program against the following functions,

1. I can plug-in the camera into network cable, then it could work to capture video independently, no need to plug-in into a computer to make it work;
2. I can remotely control the camera, e.g. control its start/stop/direction;
3. I can preform some basic setup work, e.g. setup where to store the recorded video, another example is I can setup some video parameters, like bit rate.

Any recommendations which type of camera and what software SDK to use? .Net code/solution appreciated. :-)

thanks in advance, 
George

Answer (score 2):

If you have the cash... take a look at [Rovio](http://www.meetrovio.com/). I think it comes with a full API and you would have a cool toy to play with after you finish your project.

Comment: Ps. If you're done, send it to me.

Comment: Is Rovio a network camera which we could program against (I am confused I browsed the site and not find anything claims that it is a network camera)? I am confused. Appreciate if you could send me a specific model of Rovio and talks about how it could achieve my purpose. :-)

Comment: Based on Amazon comments Rovio doesn't seem to great a product...

Comment: @schooner, whatever product is fine. I am just looking for some network video camera to program easily to achieve my purpose. Any recommendations? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at this:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WindowsVistaSideBarGadgetForAirLinkWebCam.aspx

Not sure about being able to control the camera itself but gives a basic intro to some networked webcam related interfacing.

Comment: Cool document schooner, I read through both the document and a quick start guide from Airlink. What I need is a solution (some code) to control network camera start/stop, and also control which location should be the recorded video located. But I do not find such sample codes (or no code needed?), appreciate if you could share some of your insight about how to implement this or recommend some code samples/documents.